# Can I inject new jobs into the Quartz JDBCJobStore without clustering enabled?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cluster-computing

I have several web-servers and need them to use Quartz. The clustering feature of Quartz would be ideal, but it requires that the servers clocks are in complete sync. They have a very scary warning about this:

> Never run clustering on separate machines, unless their clocks are synchronized using some form of time-sync service (daemon) that runs very regularly (the clocks must be within a second of each other).

I cannot guarantee complete clock synchronization, so instead of using the clustering feature I was thinking to have a single Quartz instance (with a stand-by for fail-over). Having a single instance executing jobs is not a problem, but I still need all of the web servers to be able to schedule jobs.

Can I directly add jobs into the JDBCJobStore from the web servers, and will they be picked up by the (non-clustered) Quartz server? I would be doing this by creating schedule instances in the web servers to add jobs. These instances would never be started, just used to access the JobStore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote a test program that creates a "non-clustered" Quartz scheduler using the same JobStore as the "real" scheduler (also non-clustered), and schedules jobs. After a few seconds, these jobs do get executed, so it seems to work.

**Update:** I cross-posted this question to the Quartz forum, and [got the answer that this should work](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/2761.page). In a [related question](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/2764.page) they state that

> The jobs can be inserted into that database by another process by:
>
> 1- using the rmi features of quartz from another process, and using the quartz API
>
> 2- instantiating a scheduler within another process (e.g. webapp), also pointing it to the same database, but NOT start()ing that scheduler instace, and the using the quartz api to schedule jobs.

Comment: Does this imply that when you have a jobstore, all jobs will be shared between all Quartz schedulers? I can't find any documentation on what a jobstore is actually being used for.